# How do you add characters to a line in python in an existing text file?

Tags: python, file, text

Suppose i have the text file:

```
apple  
banana  
fruit
```

how would i get that to :

```
1.apple  
2.banana  
3.fruit
```

Is there a way to do this in python ?

```
myfile=open("dates.txt","a")
   for i in range(14):
myfile.write(i)
   myfile.write("\n")
```

Comment: Yes. Can you post some of your code? Surely you've written some code?

Comment: Open the file, read and update the data, write it out again. Try it out then come back if you have questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use [`fileinput.input()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/fileinput.html#fileinput.input) and its `inplace` parameter for tasks such as this. Taking advantage of Python3.6's [f-strings](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#f-strings), here is a complete example:

```
import fileinput

for i, line in enumerate(fileinput.input(inplace=True), 1):
    print(f'{i}.{line.rstrip()}')
```

Sample usage:

```
$ cat groceries.txt 
apple
banana
fruit
$ python3 numberize.py groceries.txt 
$ cat groceries.txt 
1.apple
2.banana
3.fruit
$
```

Answer (score 0):

First open your file and read each line with `readlines()` to return a list of the contnse.  Then initerate through your list giving a variable the number you wish to give it.  Add the value of i (as a string) to the desired ., write over your existing file adding part of the list by slicing.

```
with open('first.txt') as pri:
    a = pri.splitlines() 
for i in range(1, len(a)+1):

    part = str(i) + '.'

    with open('first.txt', 'w') as file:
        file.write(part + a[i-1])
```